# Array comparison for equality

Tags: java

I've checked and noticed there are several other threads concerning this topic, however I didn't find any that would directly aim at this specific question, neither did I see answers to it.
So here is my code :

```
    public static boolean equals(int[] array1, int[] array2)
    {
    boolean trueFalse = true;
    while(array1.length == array2.length)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        if(array1[i] == array2[j])
        {
            i++;
            j++;
            return trueFalse;
        }
        else
        {
            trueFalse = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return trueFalse;
```

I have 2 arrays :

```
    int[] array = {2, 30, 22, 1, 5};
    int[] array1 = {2, 30, 4, 1, 5};
```

Although they are clearly not equal the program returns *true*.
I am aware of the inbuilt function *Arrays.equals()*, however I want to do it manually in order to understand the function in its entirety.

Comment: Look at your loop, if the content at the first index is the same, your method immediately returns `true` .

Comment: Same goes for arrays with different lengths

Comment: `while(array1.length == array2.length)` this is either always true or never true. You can't (or shouldn't) use it for a while-loop condition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. If the arrays are of different lengths, then they are not equal, so return immediately.
2. Use a for loop to iterate through the arrays.
3. Only return true after the whole loop is finished and no difference has been found.

```
public static boolean equals(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    if (array1.length != array2.length) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i) {
        if (array1[i] != array2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The [`Arrays.equals` implementation](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(int,%20int)) is pretty similar to this. It also null-checks both arrays to avoid throwing a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: This would through a NullPointerException if either of the passed arrays is null. Although it wasn't specified in the question, the [equals contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) specifies _"For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false"_. On top of that Arrays.equals() also returns false if either of the arguments is null. A correct implementation should also check for null arrays.

Comment: @Emiel This is nothing to do with the equals contract. This is not an implementation of `x.equals(y)`. This is a static method. And whether you want it to throw an exception or to silently return false if you pass null into it depends on your use case, which is not specified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```java
boolean check(int[] arr1, int[] arr2){
    if (arr1.length != arr2.length) return false;

    for(int i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
        if (arr1[i] != arr2[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that the `while` loop will work only once same for the `if()` statement, to compare two arrays you can use the code below:

```
public static boolean equals(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    if (array1.length != array2.length) {
        return false;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            if (array1[i] != array2[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Set your control variable (I've renamed it to `equal`) to true and if anything fails (arrays aren't the same size or an element isn't equal) then set it to false, break and return.

Note that you only need one index since the arrays have to be the same size and an array, to be equal, must have the same elements in the same order.

Also, somewhat a matter of opinion, but having only one return statement can be beneficial for readability and maintenance.

```
public static boolean equals(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
boolean equal = true;
if (array1.length == array2.length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if (array1[i] != array2[i]) {
            equal = false;
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    equal = false;
}
return equal;
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `return` when `(array1[i] == array2[j])`

also `while` will loop forever

this is how the code should be:

```
public static boolean equals(int[] array1, int[] array2)
{

if(array1.length != array2.length) return false;

int i = 0;
int j = 0;
while(i < array1.length)  //or i < array2.length
{

    if(array1[i] == array2[j])
    {
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```